# Using ctypes with cuda, getting segfault (core dumped) error at end of script

Tags: python, memory-management, cuda, segmentation-fault, ctypes

I'm using ctypes in python to call some cuda functions and keep track of the pointers, but I ran into a segfault so I've wittled the issue down to the following.

Python calls a cuda function which allocates and then free memory on the gpu. If that's all I do, then this works fine.  But if I also define a numpy array and try to take its squared norm (`np.dot(a, a)`), then, if `a` is sufficiently big, I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Here is the essential code

cuda code `debug.cu`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C" {
void all_together( size_t N)
{
    void*d;
    int size = N *sizeof(float);
    int err;

    err = cudaMalloc(&d, size);
    if (err != 0) printf("cuda malloc error: %d\n", err);

    err = cudaFree(d);
    if (err != 0) printf("cuda free error: %d\n", err);
}}
```

python code `master.py`:

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

dll = ctypes.CDLL('./cuda_lib.so', mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)

def build_all_together_f(dll):
    func = dll.all_together
    func.argtypes = [c_size_t]
    return func

__pycu_all_together = build_all_together_f(dll)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 5001 # if this is less, the error doesn't show up

    a = np.random.randn(N).astype('float32')

    da = __pycu_all_together(N)

    # toggle this line on/off to get error
    #np.dot(a, a)

    print 'end of python'
```

compile: `nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -shared -o cuda_lib.so debug.cu`

run: `python master.py`

Note: this was previously another question but I deleted that and rewrote this to be more compact and to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated CUDA to version 5.5, problem went away!